# arm-linux-gnueabi-g++: .so file not recognized

Tags: compiler-errors, g++, lego-mindstorms-ev3, pysmt, mathsat

I would like to compile MathSat on an EV3 Mindstorm with [ev3dev](https://www.ev3dev.org/) as OS.

For this, I am using the installer given by [PySMT](https://github.com/pysmt/pysmt) (PySMT is  successfully installed): `pysmt-install --msat`

Additionally, I installed some necessary packages:

```
sudo apt-get install gcc
sudo apt-get install g++
sudo apt-get install libgmp3-dev
sudo apt-get install musl-dev
```

But, I get the following error message:

```
arm-linux-gnueabi-g++ -pthread -shared -Wl,-O1 -Wl,-Bsymbolic-functions -Wl,-z,relro -fno-strict-aliasing -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-05WwKQ/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wl,-z,relro -Wdate-time -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -g -fdebug-prefix-map=/build/python2.7-05WwKQ/python2.7-2.7.13=. -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security build/temp.linux-armv5tejl-2.7/mathsat_python_wrap.o -L../lib -Wl,-R$ORIGIN -lmathsat -lgmpxx -lgmp -o build/lib.linux-armv5tejl-2.7/_mathsat.so
../lib/libmathsat.so: file not recognized: File format not recognized
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
error: command 'arm-linux-gnueabi-g++' failed with exit status 1
```

Comment: What does the command `file ../lib/libmathsat.so` say?

Comment: `../lib/libmathsat.so: ELF 64-bit LSB shared object, x86-64, version 1 (GNU/Linux), dynamically linked, BuildID[sha1]=c35ddd9742e07f033305aa3247062483ff411472, not stripped`

Comment: `x86-64` - the library is for PC architecture, the binary you're trying to build is for ARM (also, armv5 would be 32-bit). You may need to rebuild the library with your toolchain. Or install a version of that library built for the correct architecture from somewhere.